# Is it possible enable AirPlay for specific AVAudioPlayer instances

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, mpvolumeview

I have an app with multiple AVAudioPlayer instances. One instance is for background music and the other instances are sound effects.

I want the user the to have the ability to have the music routed over airplay but not the sound effects. I always want the sound effects to stay on the phone speaker/headphones.

MPVolumeView allows me to route all instances of AVAudioPlayer over to airplay. However, I want to control this for each instance of AVAudioPlayer in my app.

Is this possible? or will I have to delve into lower layer audio APIs to have this level of control?

NOTE: I can't use the system sounds API due to nature of the sound effects I am playing in my app. I know by default that never goes to airplay but it's not suitable for me in this situation.